# Error in calculating a binomial sum

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I need to show that $$\sum_{k}\binom{n+k-1}{n+\alpha-1}\binom{\beta-k-1}{n-k} = \binom{n+\beta-1}{n-\alpha}$$.

**Proof**:  Putting $n-k = m$, L.H.S becomes,
\begin{align*}
& \sum_{m}\binom{2n-m-1}{n+\alpha-1}\binom{\beta-n+m-1}{m}\\
&= \sum_{m} \binom{2n-m-1}{n-m-\alpha}\binom{\beta-n+m-1}{m} \quad \quad \text{by symmetry}\\
&= \sum_{m} \binom{2n-m-1}{(n-\alpha)-m}\binom{\beta-n+m-1}{m}\\
&= \binom{n+\beta-2}{n-\alpha} \quad \quad \text{by Vandermonde convolution}
\end{align*}

Note: 1) Symmetry says: $$\binom{n}{r} = \binom{n}{n-r}$$
2) Vandermonde convolution says $$\sum_k \binom{r}{k}\binom{s}{n-k}=\binom{r+s}{n}$$

Kindly someone tell, where am I getting wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vandermonde does not involve the summation index in the top of the binomial coefficients.  If it did, you could more simply obtain the same false result by first replacing $\binom{n+k-1}{n-\alpha-1}$ with $\binom{n+k-1}{k-\alpha}$.

Comment: Thanks. Any tip on how to solve this?

Comment: Apply $$\sum_k \binom{\ell-k}{m}\binom{q+k}{n}=\binom{\ell+q+1}{m+n+1},$$ which is (5.26) in *Concrete Mathemtics*.

Comment: It's done. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I used $5.26$ but couldn't get the answer. This is my attempt.

Comment: \begin{align*}
  &\sum_{k\geq \text{max}(\alpha,\beta)}^{n}\binom{n+k-1}{n+\alpha-1}\binom{\beta-k-1}{n-k}\\
   &=\sum_{k\geq \text{max}(\alpha,\beta)}^{n}\binom{n+k-1}{n+\alpha-1}\binom{\beta-k-1}{\beta-n-1}\\
   &=\binom{n+\beta-1}{\alpha+\beta-1}\\
   &=\binom{n+\beta-1}{n-\alpha}
\end{align*}

Comment: I tried to put the index $k$ in the upper parts only. So I used binomial symmetry in first line to get second line, which now I know that it wasn't correct. As $\beta-k-1<0$, we can't use symmetry here. But how should I get the index only in the upper parts to that I can use $5.26$? How can I get rid of $k$ in the below part of second binomial. Any help please?

Comment: What you did is what I had in mind.

Comment: oh...I have tried my best, pls let me know if u get any hint. thanks

Comment: I think I have done it. Can you please let me know if the below calculation is correct? $$\sum_{k}\binom{-n-i}{k-i}\binom{n-j}{n-k} = \sum_{k\geq i}^{n}\binom{-n-i}{k-i}\binom{n-j}{n-k}$$?

Comment: So I can use here $5.22$, am I right? Note that $1\leq i,j \leq n$ and $n$ is a positive integer.